# SublimeREPL for Python on a portable version of Sublime Text 3 and portable Python?

Tags: python, portability, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimerepl

I'm trying to get SublimeREPL to work on Python code that is being edited in a portable version of Sublime Text 3. I would like to have a SublimeREPL setup using the portable version of Python that is installed on a USB stick, but I'm not sure how... Also, I wouldn't mind knowing how to setup SublimeREPL to use a version of Python that's installed on my Windows desktop.

**MY SETUP:**

I'm running a portable version of Python 2.7.6.1 (http://portablepython.com/wiki/PortablePython2.7.6.1/ ) on a USB stick, installed under: "*H:\Python\Portable Python 2.7.6.1*"

Also, I'm running a portable version of Sublime Text 3 Build 3059 (http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203059.zip ) on the same USB stick, installed under: "*H:\Sublime\3*"

So far the only thing I have tried is updating the SublimeREPL user settings to:

```
{
    "default_extend_env": {
        "PATH": "{PATH}:H:\\Python\\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\\IDLE-Portable.exe"
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
{
"default_extend_env": {
    "PATH": "{PATH}:\\Python\\Portable Python 2.7.6.1\\IDLE-Portable.exe"}
}
```

Instead of specifying your drive letter, "\\" will go the path relative to the current drive (root of the USB). This will prevent the settings file from breaking while changing computers.